# XAMPP MySQL issue

Tags: mysql, xampp

MySQL is not starting in my XAMPP stack. Please see error log below:

---

```
2014-06-16 08:17:19 31764 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/lampp/var/mysql
2014-06-16 08:17:19 0 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2014-06-16 08:17:19 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2014-06-16 08:17:19 32127 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't change to run as user 'mysql' ;  Please check that the user exists!

2014-06-16 08:17:19 32127 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-06-16 08:17:19 32127 [Note] Binlog end
2014-06-16 08:17:19 32127 [Note] /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2014-06-16 08:17:19 31764 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/samuelb.desktop.amazon.com.pid ended
2014-06-16 08:18:47 32465 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/lampp/var/mysql
2014-06-16 08:18:47 0 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2014-06-16 08:18:47 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2014-06-16 08:18:47 393 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't change to run as user 'mysql' ;  Please check that the user exists!

2014-06-16 08:18:47 393 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-06-16 08:18:47 393 [Note] Binlog end
2014-06-16 08:18:47 393 [Note] /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2014-06-16 08:18:47 32465 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/samuelb.desktop.amazon.com.pid ended
2014-06-16 08:23:23 1367 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/lampp/var/mysql
2014-06-16 08:23:23 0 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2014-06-16 08:23:23 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2014-06-16 08:23:23 1744 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't change to run as user 'mysql' ;  Please check that the user exists!

2014-06-16 08:23:23 1744 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-06-16 08:23:23 1744 [Note] Binlog end
2014-06-16 08:23:23 1744 [Note] /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2014-06-16 08:23:23 1367 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/samuelb.desktop.amazon.com.pid ended
```

Can someone please take a look and tell me what to do about this? Thanks so much.

Comment: It seems that something is happening with your `mysql` user.

Answer (score 1):

ran into same problem (something to do with the mysql system user) found a solution.
exec the following commands in the terminal (xampp must be shutdown).

```
cd /opt/lampp/lib/mysql 
ls -la
adduser mysql
chown mysql:mysql -R /opt/lampp/lib/mysql
```

now start Xampp.